# how to use the best way to contact any thirdparty API's from web client

Tags: foursquare

I am new to use the foursquare API,

I want to use the foursquare api's on my web development.
my question is,
i) can I call the foursquare api's directly from the web browser with out contacting the 
server, Is there a way/mechanism to do so?
ii) If it should contact through  the server what is the best optimum way to do so.

iii) pointing me to the specific document deals above the case would be also appreciated

Much appreciated for your quick.

Answer (score 0):

For documentation and tutorials for the FourSquare API, reference:  https://developer.foursquare.com/

Specifically, you would be using JS to do what you ask.  It will be done in the web browser as it is a web API.

Get started here: https://developer.foursquare.com/start